# Distributed session storage in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, web-applications, express

I'm working on a distributed web app, and I want to use ExpressJS session to store data, so I need a distributed session storage. Alternatively, I could build my own session storage, but I don't know how to do it.

I'm using memcached (by mean of [this module](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached)) in some parts of the project different from the web app, so it could be nice to be able to use memcached as session storage.

I want something like this:

```
app.use(express.session({secret: 'something', store: new MemcachedStorage(...)}));
```

So what storage should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached) is what you are looking for:

```
app.use(express.session({ 
  secret: 'CatOnTheKeyboard', 
  store: new MemcachedStore 
}));
```

Comment: I'm testing it... it looks just what I need!

Comment: @sgmonda Also you can store session in database. If you are using "mongoose", "session-mongoose" is my suggestion. Of Course, There are more module, you can choose based on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached.
This connect module (connect is an underlying layer of express) is used to store your session in memcached.